# Setting up jQuery Modal Window Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I'm trying to add a cookie to this jQuery for a modal window for a website I'm working on. The div to be opened is #scrolltriggered and the closing id is #closebox. I have linked the jQuery Cookie ([here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)) yet the cookie line as recommended from the GitHUB page doesn't do anything. Though I know my way around HTML and CSS, I am new to jQuery, and all the code are just bits and pieces I put together from other people's scripts, so if there's any other, easier way to cookie this modal window for X number of days, I would appreciate it just as much. Thanks!

`$.cookie('renovatpop', '1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });`

```
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $limit = 5;
        function timerIncrement() {
            idleTime = idleTime + 1;
            if (idleTime > $limit) { 
                $('#scrolltriggered ').show();
                idleTime = 0;
            }
        }
        // Increment the idle time counter every second.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

        // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });

        $('#closebox').click(function() {
            $('#scrolltriggered').hide();
            $limit = 9999;
        });

        $.cookie('renovatpop', '1', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.

Scripts: [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js)(1.10+) and [jQuery cookie](http://cachedcommons.org/cache/jquery-cookie/0.0.0/javascripts/jquery-cookie.js) (I'd recommend using this locally).

```
<!-- jQuery library script -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- SCROLL POP UP -->
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and the following script:

```js
idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
        if ($.cookie('modal_shown') == null) {
        $.cookie('modal_shown', 'yes', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
    $limit = 7;
        function timerIncrement() {

            idleTime = idleTime + 1;
            if (idleTime > $limit) {
                $('#scrolltriggered ').show();
                idleTime = 0;
            }
        }
        // Increment the idle time counter every second.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 second

        // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });

        $('#closebox').click(function() {
            $('#scrolltriggered').hide();
            $limit = 9999;
        });
        }
    });
```

This script will do the following: Create a modal window function that will pop at 7 seconds after the website is fully loaded on a webpage and create a cookie named 'modal_shown' that will exist for 7 days after creation.

If you want to modify the number of seconds the modal shall appear, modify the value: $limit = 7

If you want to modify the number of days the cookie will be in the visitor's system, modify the value: expires: 7

**!important** - Remember to test this on your server, it will not work locally.